# How to use OWL.INVERSEOF using Openrdf in Java

Tags: java, rdf, owl, sesame, openrdf

I am trying to create some statements and their inverse in Java using OpenRDF's Sesame. I am following [the tutorial in the Sesame 2.7 documentation](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view) as well. Let's say I have created the following URIs and statements and added them to the Sesame repository:

```
RepositoryConnection connection;
ValueFactory factory = ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance(); 
Resource author_1 = new createURI("http://www.author.org/author_1");
Resource article_1 = new createURI("http://www.title.org/article_1");
URL wrote = factory.createURI("http://www.paper.org/wrote");
URL writtenby = factory.createURI("http://www.paper.org/writtenby");
Statement statement_1 = factory.createStatement(author_1, wrote, article_1);
connection.add(statement_1);
```

The code above is for creating a statement to describe that an author wrote an article. In the OpenRDF Workbench, I can see this statement. What I am trying to do is to do the inverse using `OWL.INVERSEOF` to get that `article_1` is written by `author_1` as follows:

```
connection.add(writtenby, OWL.INVERSEOF, wrote);
```

When I run the project and get back to the OpenRDF Workbench, I see the following statements:

```
<http://www.author.org/author_1>, http://www.paper.org/wrote, http://www.title.org/article_1>
<http://www.paper.org/writtenby>, <http://www.w3.org/2002/owl#inverseOf>, <http://www.paper.org/wrote>
```

When I click on `<http://www.paper.org/writtenby>`, I can't find the inverse statement that the `article_1 is written by author1` but I can find the `author_1 wrote article_1`. Is my way of doing this inverse wrong or do I misunderstand something with this concept? Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: I don't really use OpenRDF or Sesame, so I'm not familiar with the tools, but typically if you have `a p b` and `p owl:inverseOf q`, you'd need a reasoner to get the triple `b q a`.  Is there something in your system that's performing reasoning?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, I do not have the reasoning performance. How can apply this? May you please enlighten me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is as Joshua says. OpenRDF/Sesame doesn't have support for this kind of reasoning. I think it supports only some kind of basic RDF/S reasoning during load. It also (still) doesn't support custom rules I think.

You can achieve what you are asking by using Sesame with [OWLIM](https://www.ontotext.com/owlim). OWLIM-Lite and OWLIM-SE do have support for OWL reasoning (rule-based, forward-chaining, materialization). There is a number of [predefined rule sets supported by OWLIM](https://confluence.ontotext.com/display/OWLIMv54/OWLIM-Lite+Reasoner#OWLIM-LiteReasoner-PredefinedRuleSets). You would probably want `owl-max`.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you might want to use a real OWL reasoner such as Pellet. However, Sesame doesn't support Pellet...

Comment: Stardog (stardog.com) which uses pellet does support Sesame.

Comment: Update on the 'custom rules' remark: Sesame now supports SPIN (SPARQL Inferencing Notation) for custom reasoning.